# Because xml >=4.4.0 depends on petitparser ^3.1.0 and xml >=3.7.0 <4.4.0 depends on petitparser ^3.0.0, xml >=3.7.0 requires petitparser ^3.0.0

Tags: flutter-dependencies

[flutter_application] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_application...
Because xml >=4.4.0 depends on petitparser ^3.1.0 and xml >=3.7.0 <4.4.0 depends on petitparser ^3.0.0, xml >=3.7.0 requires petitparser ^3.0.0.

And because intl_utils 1.5.0 depends on petitparser >=1.1.3 <3.0.0 and flutter_svg >=0.18.0 depends on xml ^4.1.0, intl_utils 1.5.0 is incompatible with flutter_svg >=0.18.0.

So, because "App" depends on both flutter_svg ^0.18.0 and intl_utils 1.5.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because "App" depends on both flutter_svg ^0.18.0 and intl_utils 1.5.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter

# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
# Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
cupertino_icons: 0.1.2
google_maps_flutter: 0.5.27
google_map_location_picker: 3.2.2
mvc_pattern: 5.1.0
global_configuration: 1.5.0
http: 0.12.1
intl: 0.16.0
html: 0.14.0+3
shared_preferences: 0.5.7
flutter_html: 0.11.1
flutter_svg: ^0.18.0
location: 3.0.2
dynamic_theme: 1.0.1
flutter_inappbrowser: 2.0.2
url_launcher: 5.4.5
firebase_messaging: 6.0.13
cached_network_image: 2.2.0
fluttertoast: 4.0.1
flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.3.0
carousel_slider: 1.3.0
sticky_headers: ^0.1.8
intl_utils: ^1.6.3
photo_view: ^0.9.2
```

Comment: Can you share the pubspec.yaml code?

Comment: I shared a screenshot of my pubspec.yaml

Comment: Try installing `intl_utils: ^1.6.3` and `xml: ^4.4.0`

Comment: I installed intl_utils: ^1.6.3 and there were no errors but while running the app, At this step configuring the default Firebase app... the build keeps running for more than 10mins so I stopped it

Comment: Hello @pothurajusaichaitanya, welcome to SO. Please have a look on this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and consider replacing the images with textual data. This will improve the experience of those that are trying to answer your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `intl_utils: ^1.6.3` to `dependencies` and changing the `intl: 0.16.1` in `dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

I solved using

> Blockquote

by pothuraju sai chaitanya

I solved it by adding intl_utils: ^1.6.3 to dependencies and changing the intl: 0.16.1 in dependencies

and in the end

`dependency_overrides: intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2`